# Update table with another column in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

Test_order

```
    Order Num    Order ID   Prev Order ID
    987Y7OP89    919325     0
    987Y7OP90    1006626    919325
    987Y7OP91    1029350    1006626
    987Y7OP92    1756689    0
    987Y7OP93    1756690    0
    987Y7OP94    1950100    1756690
    987Y7OP95    1977570    1950100
    987Y7OP96    2160462    1977570
    987Y7OP97    2288982    2160462
```

Target table should be like below,

```
Order Num   Order ID    Prev Order ID
987Y7OP89   919325      0
987Y7OP90   1006626     919325
987Y7OP91   1029350     1006626
987Y7OP92   1756689     1029350
987Y7OP93   1756690     1756689
987Y7OP94   1950100     1756690
987Y7OP95   1977570     1950100
987Y7OP96   2160462     1977570
987Y7OP97   2288982     2160462
987Y7OP97   2288900     2288982
```

Prev Order ID should be updated with the Order ID from the previous record from the same table.

I'm trying to create a dummy data set and update..but it's not working..

```
WITH A AS
(SELECT ORDER_NUM, ORDER_ID, PRIOR_ORDER_ID,ROWNUM RID1 FROM TEST_ORDER),B AS (SELECT ORDER_NUM, ORDER_ID, PRIOR_ORDER_ID,ROWNUM+1 RID2 FROM TEST_ORDER)
SELECT A.ORDER_NUM,B.ORDER_ID,A.PRIOR_ORDER_ID,B.PRIOR_ORDER_ID FROM A,B WHERE RID1 = RID2
```

Comment: Where is your `update` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sql-server you cannot use window function in update statement, not positive but don't think so in Oracle either.  Anyway to get around that you can just update a cte as follows.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,NewPreviousOrderId = LAG(OrderId,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY OrderNum)
    FROM
       TableName
)

UPDATE cte
    SET PrevOrderId = NewPreviousOrderId
```

And if you want to stick with the ROW_NUMBER route you were going this would be the way of doing it.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderNum) AS RowNum 
    FROM
       TableName
)

UPDATE c1
    SET PrevOrderId = c2.OrderId
FROM
    cte c1
    INNER JOIN cte c2
    ON (c1.RowNum - 1) = c2.RowNum
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Oracles Analytical Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) (also called Window functions) to pick up the value from the previous order:

```
UPDATE Test_Order 
SET ORDERID = LAG(ORDERID, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY ORDERNUM ASC) 
WHERE PrevOrderId = 0
```

[See here for the documentation on LAG()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm)